# How to put a copied command in a command block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

If you have copied a zombie herobrine command what do you press on your computer to put the command in the command block?

Comment: if you have a awnser that worked then you can click the cheak mark on that awnswer

Answer (score 7):

You can use Copy and Paste.

Highlight the text you want to copy and press Ctrl-C (Command-C on a Mac). To paste it, press Ctrl-V (or Command-V).

Answer (score 0):

You basically click a command block and you copy a link and then click ctrl-v on your key board if you don't have ctrl key do command-v on Mac

Answer (score 0):

1.highlight the command

2.copy the command

3.open minecraft

4.open the world

5.do /give  username minecraft:command_block then press enter

6.place it down open the command block

7.do ctrl+v in the box

8.do /give username minecraft:redstone_block then press enter

9.place the redstoneblock next to the command block

10.then you are done

Answer (score 0):

You press this possible combination at the GUI of the Command block :

- Ctrl + V
- Strg + V
- Cmd  + V

Strg is for german keyboard.
Cmd is for Mac keyboard.