# How to copy and paste in command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Hey I need to copy and paste a command but I don't know how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a copied command in a command block?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/207285/how-to-put-a-copied-command-in-a-command-block)

Answer (score 10):

Simply use <kbd>Shift</kbd> and the arrow keys to select the command. Then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to copy the command and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste it in the new command block.

On a Mac, use <kbd>Cmd</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

Comment: and Cmd for mac

Comment: To copy the entirety of a certain Command block or Text press Ctrl+A to select it all then Ctrl+C to copy it.  Might be quicker than pressing shift and going over 280 characters.  Oh and after you hit Ctrl+A you can use shift+Left or Right Arrow Key to adjust what is selected.

Answer (score 0):

You can do <kbd>Cmd</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> then click the middle scroll button to get the command block and the NBT of the command block is going to be copied. Then when you place the command block down the command would be there ready for you.